# posix shell: stdout to file, exitcode to a variable and last line of stderr to another variable

Tags: shell, posix, stdout, stderr, exit-code

I implemented the following in POSIX shell (not bash):

fail.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo something useful
echo warning 1 >&2
echo warning 2 >&2
echo an error message >&2
exit 100
```

The command prints something I want to use on stdout, some warnings on stderr and an error message on stderr as well before failing with exit code 100.

success.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo something useful
echo warning 1 >&2
echo warning 2 >&2
exit 0
```

This command prints something to stdout and some warnings to stderr but finishes successfully with exit code 0.

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

script=$1
rm -f success
msg=$({ $script > useful; touch success; } 2>&1 | tail -1;)

if [ -f success ]; then
        echo success
else    
        echo failure
        echo last error was: $msg
fi
```

In this script I want to run either of those two scripts and provide the following functionality:

- the output of the scripts must be redirected to a file
- the last line of stderr must be saved to a variable so that I can print that last line later in case the command didnt exit successfully
- I want to detect whether or not the command exited successfully by checking its exit status

My script test.sh achieves all of that but it uses an external file. Since I use `-e` the `touch` will only be executed if `$script` executed successfully. Can I capture the exit code of `$script` without this technique?

The script must be written in POSIX shell and must use `-e`.

Comment: Why must it use `-e`? Is this a programming contest or homework?

Comment: @Barmar neither - it is an addition to an existing shell script whose author insists on using `-e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh -e

script=$1
if msg=$($script 2>&1 >useful); then
    echo success
else
    echo failure
    msg=$(echo "$msg" | tail -1)
    echo last error was: $msg
fi
```

Comment: you probably mean `msg=$({ $script > useful; } 2>&1);` ?

Comment: No, I don't think that format is necessary, so I rewrote it in the simpler form. Redirections are implemented left to right, so this is equivalent.

Comment: but with this `useful` also contains the output of stderr

Comment: I just tried `./fail.sh 2>&1 >useful` and `useful` only contained `something useful`.

Comment: sorry, my error - I mixed up the order - Thanks a ton for your help! I didnt know one could do it like that!